# How to edit the table header in htm file by using python?

Tags: python, html

I have a table with following header:

```
<html>
<body>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Car</th>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</body>
</html>
```

In python I have a list which **a=["Brand", "ColorCode", "CarPlate"]**, so anyone have ideas on how to used python to edit the header in the htm file and the output will become :

```
<html>
<body>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Brand</th>
<th>ColorCode</th>
<th>CarPlate</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: `I have a table ....` - in a file? In a remote location? As part of a website you provide using python? As result when crawling someting? Please be more specific .

Comment: + Where the changes must be displayed, in a local file ?

Comment: the table is html table

Answer (score 0):

your minimal requirement is an xml parser. as @Rakesh told you `BeautifulSoup` is the most used method but it's a third-party library. python's `ElementTree` should be good enough here

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

a=["Brand", "ColorCode", "CarPlate"]
data="""<thead>
<tr>
<th>Car</th>
<th>Color</th>
<th>Number</th>
</tr>
</thead>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
ths = root.find("tr").findall("th")
for i, th in enumerate(ths):
    th.text = a[i]

print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

gives the expected result

Comment: hi, if i add <body> in data, then it will not worl already, that mean i not able to add others tag in data, anysolution on that?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TRYSugeb.py", line 35, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(mystring)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
    return parser.close()
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 20, column 13

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\TRYSugeb.py", line 35, in <module>
    root = ET.fromstring(mystring)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in XML
    return parser.close()
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 20, column 13

Comment: the code is simple enough for you to find out how it works